# dir() a __class__ attribute?

Tags: python

```
class Foo:
  pass

>>> f = test.Foo()
```

Lets look into the class instance ...

```
>>> dir(f)
['__add__', [__class__] ...]
```

Oooh! Lets look into the class instance metadata ...

```
>>> dir(f.__class__)
['__add__', [__class__] ...]
```

hmm ... was expecting attributes of `__class__` ; but returns back attributes of `f`

Trying a hit and trial ...

```
>>> dir(f.__class__.__class__)
['__abstractmethods__', '__base__' ...]
```

hmm ... why twice a charm?

Comment: I have a feeling this behavior depends on your Python version. I get different behavior in 2.6. What version are you using?

Comment: There's also a difference between the results given for new-style classes and old-style classes on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dir(f)` and `dir(f.__class__)` are showing the attributes of two different things.  It's just that your empty object has the same attributes as its own class.  Try this:

```
>>> class Foo:
...  def __init__(self):
...   self.a = 17
...
>>> f = Foo()
>>> 'a' in dir(f)
True
>>> 'a' in dir(f.__class__)
False
```

Comment: okay! but what is the difference between `dir(f.__class__)` and `dir(f.__class__.__class__)`? (I know that `__name__` and `__bases__` are attr of `__class__` but I don't see it in `f.__class__`)

Comment: It's an unfortunate fact that an object can have attributes that dir() doesn't report.